# javascript for loop not iterating completely through object

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, iteration, javascript-objects

I'm currently experimenting with dynamically loading data from a JS Object into html containers by iterating over it with a For Loop.

The wall I have hit seems to be because the For Loop won't iterate through the whole object, even though I'm setting high threshold of the For Loop based on a calculation of the amount of objects that are held within the JS Object.

A working solution will have all objects loaded into their respective html containers. At this point I'm not fussed about showing the objects inside the achievements property object.

This experiment is to better understand Pure Javascript so no Jquery or framework suggestions please.

Data Object:

```
var data = { projects: [{
  title: "GET BORN",
  tags: ["Live Events", "Stage Design", "Event Promotion", "Music"],
  date_started: "21/09/12",
  date_finished: "Finish Date",
  description: "Music events that explores the underground sound",
  achievements: [{milestone:"Launched Brand", date:"datetime",  details:"blah"}, {milestone:"Hosted First Night", date:"datetime",  details:"moreblah"}, {milestone:"Sold Out Lakota +1000 People",   date:"datetime", details:"moreblah"}],
  position: 1  
}, {
  title: "FAIRSTREAM",
  tags: ["Web Application", "Trademark", "Music streaming"],
  date_started: "10/05/16",
  date_finished: "Finish date",
  description: "Equal opportunity music streaming application",
  achievements: [{milestone:"Launched Brand", date:"datetime", details:"blah"}],
  position: 2
}]}
```

View Generating Function:

```
const buildProjectView = (dataSet) => {
  const currentProjectIndex = 0
  let dataLen = Object.keys(dataSet.projects[currentProjectIndex]).length
  // console.log(dataLen)

  let objKey = Object.keys(dataSet.projects[currentProjectIndex])
  let objValue = Object.values(dataSet.projects[currentProjectIndex])
  // console.log(objValue)

  for (let i = 0; i < dataLen; i++) {
    // console.log("count: " + i)
    console.log(objKey[i] + ": " + objValue[i])

    let theTitle = document.getElementById(objKey[i])
    let content = document.createTextNode(objValue[i])
    theTitle.appendChild(content)
  }
}

window.onload = buildProjectView(data)
```

HTML Boilerplate:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Mysite Playground</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <section class="head">
      <h1 id="title"/>
      <h2 id="description"/>
      <h3 id="date_started"/>
    </section>
    <section class="body">
      <p id="position">#</p>
      <p id="achievements"/>
      <p id="tags"/>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My coding test platform with example and some basic styling:
https://codepen.io/wntwrk/pen/bqXYMO

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: `const currentProjectIndex = 0
  let dataLen = Object.keys(dataSet.projects[currentProjectIndex]).length` - this is only processing the object with `title: "GET BORN",` in it, and always returns 7.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you a starting point to give you something to work with.

You have an array with arrays in it and an array of objects.

Note that simply "pushing" stuff into the DOM on the existing markup/boilerplate does not help you, you need to clone that to allow more instances - which is what I did.

Using this data provided:

```
/*jshint esversion: 6 */
var data = {
  projects: [{
    title: "GET BORN",
    tags: ["Live Events", "Stage Design", "Event Promotion", "Music"],
    date_started: "21/09/12",
    date_finished: "Finish Date",
    description: "Music events that explores the underground sound",
    achievements: [{
      milestone: "Launched Brand",
      date: "datetime",
      details: "blah"
    }, {
      milestone: "Hosted First Night",
      date: "datetime",
      details: "moreblah"
    }, {
      milestone: "Sold Out Lakota +1000 People",
      date: "datetime",
      details: "moreblah"
    }],
    position: 1
  }, {
    title: "FAIRSTREAM",
    tags: ["Web Application", "Trademark", "Music streaming"],
    date_started: "10/05/16",
    date_finished: "Finish date",
    description: "Equal opportunity music streaming application",
    achievements: [{
      milestone: "Launched Brand",
      date: "datetime",
      details: "blah"
    }],
    position: 2
  }]
};
```

I added some functions to hopefully make it easier to understand.

```
// convert the "boilerplate" to a class based avoiding duplicate id's
function idToClass(node) {
  var child, nodes = node.childNodes;
  for (var i = 0, len = nodes.length; i < len; i++) {
    child = nodes[i];
    if (typeof child.id === 'string' && child.id !== "") {
      child.className = child.id;
      child.removeAttribute("id");;
    }
    if (child.childNodes && child.childNodes.length) {
      idToClass(child);
    }
  }
}

let addItem = (project, aclone, name) => {
  let el = aclone.getElementsByClassName(name);
  if (el.length && typeof project[name] !== "object") {
    el[0].textContent = project[name];
  }
  if (el.length && typeof project[name] === "object") {
    /// do something with objects like the "achievements"
  }
};

let addProject = (project, aclone) => {
  var k = Object.keys(project);
  k.forEach(function(item) {
    addItem(project, aclone, item);
  });
  return aclone;
};

const buildProjectView = (dataSet) => {
  let y = document.getElementsByClassName('container');
  //clone and change ids to classes
  let aclone = y[0].cloneNode(true);
  idToClass(aclone);
  for (let i = 0; i < dataSet.projects.length; i++) {
    let n = addProject(dataSet.projects[i], aclone.cloneNode(true));
    y[0].parentNode.appendChild(n, aclone);
  }
  // COULD remove the boilerplate here:
  // y[0].removeNode();
};

window.onload = buildProjectView(data);
```